# HPE Proliant Gen8 FlexibleLOM options for homelab network

Tags: networking, fiber, hp-proliant, 10gbit

In my homelab rack I've got a pair of DL360p's and a pair of DL380's (one P, one E). Network hardware wise I've got a 24 port Brocade 300 and a 48 port POE+ Avaya switch with a single SFP+ port. (3549GTS-PWR+).

Originally I had considered just using SFP+ LOMs (530FLR-SFP+, 560FLR-SFP+, 571FLR-SFP+), but having recently obtained the Brocade FC switch was thinking maybe using one of the FlexFabric LOMs (554FLR-SFP+, 556FLR-SFP+) is more suited? I haven't dealt with FC before, so not sure if this is the better choice. The DL380's both are full of LFF drives and are essentially the storage backbone. The rack also has 2.5Gb ethernet in, but was aiming for all internal networking to 8/10gb.

Given the available hardware listed, what's my best approach for networking everything?
It seems finding a switch with more than 2-4 SFP+ ports isn't particularly affordable, but FC is kind of ancient (At least 8gb).

Comment: Do you *want* to deal with Fibre Channel specifically? It's meant for SCSI storage networks and not really suited for carrying IP traffic, if that's what you were planning.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an IP-based network, you'll want Ethernet.

Fibre Channel is not an option for that; it's primarily a *storage* network meant to carry SCSI, and although IP-over-FC technically "exists", it is not widely supported at all – for example, Linux removed IPoFC support in 2010 or so.

So you can use it for storage, probably, but it won't be enough to build a full LAN.

(These days it's more common to do the opposite and run everything over Ethernet, e.g. Fibre Channel is replaced by FCoE or iSCSI or NVMe-oF, and InfiniBand is replaced by RoCE.)

InfiniBand might work (though from what I've heard it requires an InfiniWallet), as IP-over-IB *does* exist on both Windows and Linux, but again it'll be easier to do the same over Ethernet. Most 10 Gbps Ethernet NICs can also do RDMA using "RoCE" which is basically InfiniBand-over-Ethernet, anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure of your definition of "affordable", but e.g. TL-SX3008F with eight 10G Ethernet SFP+ ports seems to be within range. Beyond that it does get expensive.

Comment: While I'd not seen this (Mostly been looking at used hardware), £200 for 8 SFP+ ports still seems somewhat steep. Had figured there would be some used network gear that was proportionally priced to the rest of the gear I have from that era. (Sub < £100)

Didn't really want to go down the Infiniband route, simply as I have nothing that supports it and it seemed a bit overkill for a single home rack. Had hoped to find *some* use for my FC switch, but no real loss if not. I will go and read into FC more, don't quite think I understood it's practical uses. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you could probably still use FC for storage and 1Gbps Ethernet for other things, depending on whether any of your other systems support FC (e.g. a VM host could use FC to access a storage server).

Comment: That's certainly one use case I could have for FC. Does the storage host have to be a storage array type device though? Or is the DL380P used for most storage be able to use a FlexFabric PCI-e or FlexLom card for FC to enable my VM host to access said storage via it's own FC link (presumably via the FC switch)?

Comment: I believe Linux can act as a Fibre Channel "target" (as part of the same subsystem that provides iSCSI target support, I think?).